# Panel OLS in statsmodels (because it's deprecated in Pandas?)

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, regression, statsmodels

It seems in the latest version of pandas, all the ols functionality has been deprecated (pandas.stats is effectively gone, and doesn't have PanelOLS or the ols function).  I am trying to run a panel regression with statsmodels, but can't find an effective way to do so?  Previously I could use code like this:

```
panel_ols = ols(y=DataFrame, x=DataFrame, ...,)
```

This would estimate coefficients using all the data in a single panel regression.

Any way to do this now?

Comment: You could use the sklearn OLS Regressor classifier.

Comment: In addition to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ recommendation, `numpy` has builtin functionality for OLS regression. See- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on statsmodel docs, it appears you want [Linear Mixed Effects Models](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/mixed_linear.html), but I'm not a big user of statsmodels so I'm just going by documentation.

Some more general info on the status of panel and OLS:  panel is deprecated and OLS has been removed as of pandas version 0.20.1.  Here is the info from "What's New":

[Deprecate Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-panel)

> Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. **The recommended way to represent 3-D data are with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame via the to_frame() or with the [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) package.** Pandas provides a to_xarray() method to automate this conversion. For more details see Deprecate Panel documentation [(GH13563)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13563).

[Remove OLS, Fama-Macbeth, etc.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes)

> pandas.stats.fama_macbeth, pandas.stats.ols, pandas.stats.plm and pandas.stats.var, as well as the top-level pandas.fama_macbeth and pandas.ols routines are removed. **Similar functionaility can be found in the [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org)
>    package.** [(GH11898)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11898)